# Grinding noise on engine shut off

Tags: chevrolet, noise, astro, grinding

I have a 1995 Chevy Astro.  I had an auto shop change the fuel injection spider.  When I got it back, I noticed there was a screeching, grinding noise coming from around the intake manifold when I shut off the engine.  I have a video here of the noise.  https://youtu.be/KY3U9IqTA7Y . Much appreciated if you guys can diagnose it for me and tell me what the problem might be.

Comment: If it did not do this before, you should consider taking it back to the shop that did the work to have them fix it.

Comment: Maybe my hearing is going, but I'm not hearing anything which sounds abnormal. At any rate, I don't hear anything which could be construed as a "grinding noise".

Comment: What is a fuel injection spider?

Comment: @zipzit - It's a different type of fuel injection system with a central pump going out to individual injectors looks kind of like a spider, especially with a V8 (though this is a V6). Was not what I consider GM'S bright shiney moment in fuel injection.

Comment: Sorry but I have to agree with PAULSTER2 . The only noise that I heard that was close to a grinding noise was the starter when you started it up.